# MS Access VBA for import path change and import

Tags: vba, ms-access

My requirement is such - I have a table called as Import Details in which I have provided the file names of .csv files that I have to import. I am expecting to click a button called as Change Path, on a form when a pop up opens and ask me to choose the path for the files. I choose a path, say `\\network\abc\def\csv_files\`.

Once the path is chosen, the Saved Imports (ImportExportSpec) under the menu External Data should have the new path instead of old path, but the end file name should remain the same. If I choose `F\Documents\CSV` files later as the path, the new path should reflect for all the tables listed in Saved Imports.

Can I have a code for the same please ? I am unable to sort that out myself.

Answer (score 1):

Further to my answer to your earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29604364/2144390), you will need to use Access VBA to iterate through the `CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications` collection and inspect the `.XML` property of each `ImportExportSpecification` object. If it contains an

```xml
<ImportText  ... >
```

element (indicating that it is a "Saved Import") then you can update the `Path=` attribute of the `<ImportExportSpecification>` element to replace the old folder location with the new one, e.g., by changing

```xml
<ImportExportSpecification Path="C:\Users\Public\zzz.csv" ... >
```

to

```xml
<ImportExportSpecification Path="C:\New\Location\zzz.csv" ... >
```

Comment: I understand, you are hardcoding the new location. In my scenario, the path changes all the time. Is there any way I could share my ms access db here , so that it will be easy for helpers to understand

Comment: The location must be a literal value in the XML data. When the user selects a new folder then you'll just have to run a routine to update the literal `Path=` values in the applicable `ImportExportSpecification` objects.